# necesito incluir los botones del <div> adentro del php? Salen todo abajo, cuando deberia salir al lado de cada fila

Tags: php

este es el codigo. Quisiera incluir, lo tengo en la parte inferior del codigo, en este momento se observa la tabla partida con los elementos button abajo de la tabla, cuando en su normalidad deberian estar a la derecha de cada fila para ser editada o eliminada. He intentado incluirlos adentro pero me da error por todos lados, estoy comenzando con php y se me complica cuadrar el codigo.    `

```
<button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" 
                  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')"></button>
               </td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
               </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>`
```

no tengo idea como poner las llaves para que queden adentro de la tabla en cada fila, intente de todo. les agradeceria una orientacion

el codigo completo lo tengo asi 
***CODIGO COMPLETO***

```
<?php

  require_once "../php/conexion.php";
  $conn=conn();

?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h2>Tabla de registros express</h2>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
        <caption>
        <label for="caja_busqueda">Buscar</label>
        <input type="text" name="caja_busqueda" id="caja_busqueda" style="float=:right;">

         <div id="resultado"></div>
             <button class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNuevo">Agregar nuevo
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
             </button>

        </caption>

              <?php

              $mysqli = new mysqli ("localhost","root","","formulario");

              $salida = "";
              $query = "SELECT * FROM recolectores ORDER by codigo_postal";

              if(isset($_POST['consulta'])){
                  $q = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
                  $query = "SELECT CODIGO_POSTAL, LOCALIDAD, ID_RECOLECTOR from recolectores 
                  where ID_RECOLECTOR LIKE '%".$q."%'";
              }

              $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
                if($resultado->num_rows > 0){

                    $salida.="<tr>
                    <td>Nro Orden</td>
                    <td>Serie</td>
                    <td>Equipo</td>
                    <td>Cable AV</td>
                    <td>Cable HDMI</td>
                    <td>Control</td>
                    <td>Fuente</td>
                    <td>Editar</td>
                    <td>Eliminar</td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>";



                while($fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                    $salida.="<tr>
                                <td>".$fila['CODIGO_POSTAL']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['LOCALIDAD']."</td>
                                <td>".$fila['ID_RECOLECTOR']."</td>

                               </tr>";
                }

                  $salida.="</tbody></table>";
            }else {
                    $salida.="no hay datos";

                } echo $salida;


                $mysqli->close();    

?>

                  <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" 
                  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')"></button>
               </td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
               </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
`
```

el button, td,  y  quiero colocarlos adentro de las llaves de php pero me da error de sintaxis.

Comment: Hola Álvaro. Tienes una confusión. El php se usa para generar bloques html dinámicamente. Todo en tu página, es html, cada vez, que ejecutas pedazos de php estás preparando html que puede mostrarse ahí o más adelante, y de paso php te permite interactuar con bases de datos, archivos etc mientras se prepara el html. Trata de documentarte un poco al respecto y luego retomas el problema.

Comment: gracias quevedo

Comment: problema resuelto

Answer (score 0):

En php hay tres maneras de asignar cadenas a variables:

```
<?php
$variable1 = "valor uno"; dentro de comillas dobles
$variable2 = 'valor dos'; dentro de comillas simples
$variable3 = <<<MARCA
muchas líneas de contenido con $otrasvariables cuyos contenidos son expandidos 
como si se hubiera hecho echo $otrasvaiables
MARCA;
// no puede haber nada escrito después de ; en la línea MARCA; y debe ser el
// único texto en la línea (sin espacios o tabs antes)
```

En el caso del código que muestras, el bloque correspondiente a los botones puede insertarse sin error antes de la marca de cierre de php `?>` así:

```
<?php
// aquí viene todo tu código hasta el punto de cierre de la conexión
// $mysqli->close();
$botones = <<<BTNS
<button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" 
onclick="agregaform('$datos')"></button>
BTNS;
// y ahora la magia:
echo $botones;
// y finalmente cierras el bloque php
?>
```

Ahora sigue tu html normalmente y no debe producirse error siempre que `$datos` contenga o genere una cadena que pueda ser mostrada en el sitio en que se uso.

Espero te sirva. Y, no olvides documentarte al respecto de la relación `php<->html`

Comment: excelente quevedo muchas gracias